# why p-value for high-correlation data is 1? what is wrong?

Tags: python, data-analysis, correlation, p-value

I try to filter correlation matrix with p-value for the following matrix

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr
A=np.array([[ 6.02,  5.32],
       [12.18, 12.13],
       [11.08, 10.54],
       [ 9.03,  8.95],
       [ 6.08,  6.94]])
```

I use the following code

```py
def get_corr(M, g=1):

    n =np.shape(M)[0]
    out = np.empty(np.shape(M)[0])
    out_p = np.empty(np.shape(M)[0])

    out1 = np.zeros(shape=(np.shape(M)[0],np.shape(M)[0]))
    P1 = np.zeros(shape=(np.shape(M)[0],np.shape(M)[0]))
    for p in range(np.shape(M)[0]):
        for i in range(np.shape(M)[0]):

            PearsonCorrCoeff, pval = pearsonr(M[p,:], M[i,:])            
            aux = PearsonCorrCoeff
            out_p[i]= pval
            out[i] = 0 if np.isnan(aux) else aux 
            if g==1:
                if pval < (0.01):#/N:
                  aux = aux
                else: 
                  aux = 0
                  out[i] = 0 if np.isnan(aux) else aux   
            else:      
                  out[i] = 0 if np.isnan(aux) else aux    
        out1[p] = out 
        P1[p] = out_p
    return out1,P1
corr_A, P_A = get_corr(A)
```

But the answer that I get it is strange,
because the main correlation without filtering is

```py
corr_A=array([[ 1., -1.,  1., -1.,  1.],
       [-1.,  1., -1.,  1., -1.],
       [ 1., -1.,  1., -1.,  1.],
       [-1.,  1., -1.,  1., -1.],
       [ 1., -1.,  1., -1.,  1.]])
```

and the P-value matrix is

```
P_A=array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

while all should be zero, I do not know what could be the reason, has someone had the same problem before?

Comment: You're correlating arrays of just two values. This is exactly what you'd expect

Comment: Thank you @Marat when the correlation is 1, p-valu should not be zero? Why it is what I should expect? Could you explain more?

Comment: p-value only tells you how likely this is to happen by chance. Since these pairs can go only in the same or opposite direction, correlation of 1 or -1 is expected - thus, probability of it happening by chance is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on what @Marat's comment, you likely want:

```py
pearsonr(M[:,p], M[:,i])
```

**Why is -1/1 what you'd expect here?** Think about the case where `x` and `y` are just two values apiece, think about fitting a best fit line through a graph of these values. Something like:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.random.randn(2,2)

x = A[0]
y = A[1]

ax = plt.plot(x,y, "-o")
ax[0].axes.set(xlabel="x", ylabel="y")
None
```

[image]

So not too shabby!

You're probably expecting someting like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

B = np.random.randn(2,300)

x = B[0]
y = B[1]

print(pearsonr(x,y))

ax = plt.plot(x,y, "o")
ax[0].axes.set(xlabel="x", ylabel="y", title="With >two values")
None
```

[image]

As expected, not much of a correlation.

Comment: Thank you @webelo, my problem is not the correlation? My problem is the p-values, why should I get 1 for correlation 1? should not p-value be zero?

Comment: Sorry! I think this is actually quite interesting but can't write it up right this moment. Some intuition: P values are all about what would happen if one were to draw alternative samples under the null hypothesis. Here, n=2 is set. So we know that correlation will always be 1/-1 under the null. That means that the p-value - the probability of drawing an equally extreme statistic under the null  - is 1!

Comment: The [scipy docs for `pearsonr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html) have a nice discussion as to why - from a formal perspective - the p-value really doesn't make sense for n=2. In short, the implied distribution of the correlation coefficient is undefined. You might find it to be interesting to see what is returned as the p-value for 1-sided tests (`alternative` argument). 1-sided tests also don't really make sense here but it might be nice to understand how scipy copes.